# C#: Label contains no text

Tags: c#, asp.net, javascript

I would like to get the text out of a label. But the label text is set with Javascript.
On the page I can see that there is text in the label, but when I debug it shows this: "".

So how do I get the text out of a label that is set with Javascript, at least that is what I think is the problem.

My code:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtCount" runat="server" Width="50px" Font-Names="Georgia, Arial, sans-Serif" ForeColor="#444444"></asp:TextBox>
<ajaxToolkit:NumericUpDownExtender ID="NumericUpDownExtender1" runat="server" Minimum="1"
 TargetButtonDownID="btnDown" TargetButtonUpID="btnUp" TargetControlID="txtCount"  Width="20" />
<asp:ImageButton ID="btnUp" runat="server" AlternateText="up" ImageUrl="Images/arrowUp.png"
 OnClientClick="setAmountUp()" ImageAlign="Top" CausesValidation="False" />
 <asp:ImageButton ID="btnDown" runat="server" AlternateText="down" ImageUrl="Images/arrowDown.png"  OnClientClick="setAmountDown()" ImageAlign="Bottom" 
 CausesValidation="False" />

<asp:Label ID="lblKorting" runat="server" />

 <asp:Label ID="lblAmount" runat="server" />

<asp:Button ID="btnBestel" runat="server" CssClass="btn" Text="Bestel" OnClick="btnBestel_Click1" />
```

JS

```
function setAmountUp()
{
    var aantal = document.getElementById('<%=txtCount.ClientID%>').value-0;

    aantal+=1;
    calculateAmount(aantal);
}

function setAmountDown()
{
    var aantal = document.getElementById('<%=txtCount.ClientID%>').value-0;

    if(aantal > 1)
        aantal -=1;

    calculateAmount(aantal);
}

function calculateAmount(aantal)
{

    var prijs = document.getElementById('<%=lblPriceBestel.ClientID%>').innerHTML -0;   
    var totaal = 0;

    if(aantal < 2)
    {
        totaal = prijs * aantal;
        document.getElementById('<%=lblKorting.ClientID%>').innerHTML = "";
    }

    else if(aantal >= 2 && aantal < 5)
    {
        totaal = (prijs * aantal)*0.95;
        document.getElementById('<%=lblKorting.ClientID%>').innerHTML = "-5%";
    }

    else if(aantal >= 5)
    {
        totaal = (prijs * aantal)*0.90;
        document.getElementById('<%=lblKorting.ClientID%>').innerHTML = "-10%";
    }

    document.getElementById('<%=lblAmount.ClientID%>').innerHTML = totaal;
}
```

C#

```
 private OrderBO bestelling;
    protected void btnBestel_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        bestelling = new OrderBO();
        bestelling.Amount = Convert.ToInt32(lblAmount.Text); //<--- THIS IS "" in the debugger, but on the page 10
    }
```

Comment: Warren's approach looks good. However just be sure that you're not using the amount being sent from the page to create an order, because anyone can easily tamper the data that is sent from a webpage and if they figure out that you use the value from the page to calculate the amount for the order then they can easily change the value to set whatever amount they want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Text stored inside a label is not sent back to the server on a postback.  It's a one-way kind of thing.

What you should do instead is put any text you want to go back to the server into a hidden form field, like so:

ASP.NET:

```
<asp:HiddenField runat="server ID="hfAmount" />
```

JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById('<%=hfAmount.ClientID%>').value = totaal;
```

C#:

```
bestelling.Amount = Convert.ToInt32(hfAmount.Value);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I've been looking for hours to solve this error.